# How to Handle Authentication popup in selenium, which does not have WebElements

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-chromedriver, popupwindow

[image: Sign In snapshot]

Here is the detail and options I have tried.

1. As soon as URL is launched, a authenticate pop gets displayed at the top center of screen.
2. The popup does not have any webElements.(No Inspect option or F12 does not show up any elements)
3. I tried using Alert, getWindowHandle(s) nothing seems to be working.
4. I tried traditional way `driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");` Even this does not work as my URL is secured URL, does.

**Is there any way I can handle this using Java code in Selenium**

```
// Attempt 1:
String logScrn= driver.getWindowHandle();   
System.out.println(logScrn);
driver.findElement(By.id(logScrn)).sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + password");  

// Attempt 2:            
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password" + Keys.TAB);
alert.accept();
```

Comment: Which browser are you attempting this in?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Please add this information to your question text and not just a comment.